# What rpg Succeed/Fail rolling systems are out there?

Tags: skill-challenge, random-generation

I am studying how games balance skill and chance using dice based systems. There are many systems like D&D's D20 system or the Burning Wheels (unnamed D6 system) that take a blend of skill and chance to determine if an action will pass or fail. In general, I wanted to know what other skill and random based RPG conflict resolution systems are out there and how they work.

For the sake of limiting scope, I want to know if there are any existing lists or forums that detail created conflict resolution systems?
 OR
Are there any notable games on the similar production level (in terms of budget, user base, and business organization)of D&D and The Burning Wheel?

I know about the D20 system for D&D, how it uses a D20 as the basis of determining the outcome of an action given an ability score and skill of context. Also with the Burning Wheel they have the (unnamed to me) system where you roll a number of D6 equal to the level of skill, counting the rolls above 4 (or the shade value) as successes and must meet a number of successes above the challenge number.

Are there any other similar systems for other RPG games?

Comment: @BenBarden I think it's actually a list question, not a shopping question. Also off topic, but different reason. We'll have to work with Grizz to narrow it down, I think.

Comment: In perspective: there are several thousand unique RPGs on the market, and several hundred RPG families. From the games and families I've seen there are almost as many materially different resolution systems. This is a very, very big question and probably does not fit out format for the sheer impracticality of actually providing a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I think the question is more about *engines* than *systems*, if you get what I mean. I can answer that. Reason for the conclusion: reference to Burning Wheel *having an unnamed system* within it. Could it please be reopened?

Comment: Hi everyone! This may be too broad, and im not sure what a shopping question is but I think it suits more of list question. I wanted to know where I can find games with similar conflict resolution systems or a list of existing ones. More specifically, I wanted to know if there are any systems on a production scale like (D&D or The Burning Wheel) with notably unique mechanics for conflict resolution, and not a direct derivative of the mentioned systems.

Comment: This is unlikely to be opened on the basis that [our system works best when we can reliably provide a single best possible answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). On the other hand, it breaks down when we will accumulate a continuous, unending stream of answers, all of which are valid and none of which are better or worse than any other, and that is likely to be what will happen here. Being that there are hundreds of resolution mechanics, we will accumulate many dozens of answers covering 1-10 each, *some* of them trying to be fully comprehensive (but not).

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this question? Are your reasons purely academic? If there is some practical use, then we might be able to steer into a more stackable direction.

Comment: @Grizzley You may want to review [the list of RPGs on RPGGeek](https://rpggeek.com/browse/rpg). Each and every one I know of on that list has a distinct resolution mechanic created just for that game to achieve specifically just that game's goals because a successful design required it. There are few exceptions among those I know, e.g. where the game belongs to a family and uses the family's standard resolution system, e.g. most *Fate* or *Powered by the Apocalypse* games. Note the list is 100 RPGs per page and is 96 pages.

Comment: @Grizzley Also, this might be a good candidate for a discussion to have over in [chat]. The rules and general form of conversation is much more lenient there. Once you get to a certain rep (20) you can participate in chat.

Comment: There are hundreds, perhaps thousands of RPG pass/fail systems out there that might qualify for the bar you’ve set. This isn’t a type of question our site system is capable of helping. For this you probably want to ask on a discussion forum, where there are fewer restrictions on what’s on topic. [We have assembled a list of RPG discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/321) to help you get started.